# Creating multi step forms

Tags: jquery, forms, multi-step

I have been searching around for a way to create a multi step form such as: http://planner.builtbybuffalo.com/step-1/

I couldnt find any resources, just other examples, the one I am trying to create will be a 3 part process. I am going to be building this in jQuery.

I can understand the way to go from step to step, fadein/out, etc. But having a marker change and say what step.

Thoughts?

Comment: The sample URL no longer works.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this [blog post](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx) from [Janko](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/)

"Turn any webform into a powerful wizard with jQuery (FormToWizard plugin)"

Here is his [demo](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/webform_to_wizard/) .

I haven't used this plugin from him but I know that he has very good posts that I have used in the past.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

I recently have used this plugin and it worked great. It was simple to use and easy to modify for my specific needs.

Comment: Looks great! I am going to go try this out.

Comment: Very interesting but I think it does not working with browser back button.

Comment: a simple jquery plugin i wrote, i hope someone would find it helpful.. https://github.com/hirdeshvishwdewa/multiStepForm

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the steps on the timeline are evenly spaced. It might be as simple as multiplying the step number by the width and divide by the number of steps to get the distance the marker has to travel. Then use jQuery.animate to animate the position of the marker.

Sandro

Comment: thank you! I will try that, i like how that animates to the next marker.

Comment: if each form "step" is in a <div>, then you could take it as far as to build the step indicator dynamically by breaking apart the horizontal bar, each numbered circle, and (obviously) the marker into their own images, use jQuery to find out how many steps (<div>s) are in the form and loop that many times to build the indicator using the math explained above. The marker gets placed at the current step.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a full working simple three steps example, with no need to jQuery.

You just need to define the `submit_form()` function. The HTML characters `&laquo;` and `&raquo;` just print respectively « and » which might be interesting for the previous and next button characters.

```js
function shows_form_part(n){
    var i = 1, p = document.getElementById("form_part"+1);
    while (p !== null){
        if (i === n){
            p.style.display = "";
        }
        else{
            p.style.display = "none";
        }
        i++;
        p = document.getElementById("form_part"+i);
    }
}

function submit_form() {
 var sum = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value) +
            parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value) +
            parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);
  alert("Your result is: " + sum);
}
```

```html
<body onload="shows_form_part(1)">
<form>
  <div id="form_part1">
    Part 1<br>
    <input type="number" value="1" id="num1"><br>
    <!--form elements 1-->
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form_part2">
    Part 2<br>
    <input type="number" value="2" id="num2"><br>
    <!--form elements 2-->
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(1)">&laquo;</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(3)">&raquo;</button>
  </div>
  <div id="form_part3">
    Part 3<br>
    <!--form elements 3-->
    <input type="number" value="3" id="num3"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="shows_form_part(2)">&laquo;</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="submit_form()">Sum</button>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
```