# django forms with jquery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, forms

well ive been searching for the past 3 hours and I cant seem to find a good tutorial on this ... i`m looking for a tutorial on how to make a form "wizard" with jquery and django (I dont know javascript only basics) 
I need a 3 step wizard ...

first step 2 inputs

- user
- password

if user and password are in db then show 2nd step

2nd step 2 input

- email
- address (home address)

send a token to his email ...

3rd step 3 input and finish button

- new password
- retype password
- token

check if the token is valid if it is submit ...

Can you guys point me to the right direction ?

Thx a lot.

Comment: Without using javascript, there is the inbuilt Django Form Wizard: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Javascript then the "step" process will be faked, basically hiding/showing/validating fields when a user clicks a button, but it will all be in one view. Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074707/creating-multi-step-forms) for help on building that. [This](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery/) looks like a pretty good tutorial on the topic as well. You won't be changing anything on the backend, and you can use a single Django form to display all the inputs individually. Check the [Django docs on using forms in templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template) for more information on that.

If you want a "step" process using Django without using Javascript, you can use the [Django form wizard](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/).