# Is there anything similar to jFormer (particularly the survey form) available for ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins

Is there anything similar to jFormer (particularly the survey form) available for ASP.Net? I want to ensure that it is as usable as anything else built on jQuery but has no PHP dependencies. Also, I do not want to use AJAX.Net with its heavy footprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what I am after but it is close on this tumbleweed question: [Creating multi step forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074707/creating-multi-step-forms)